# Using Cordova Plugins in Ionic Inside a Controller

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

So I am trying to integrate touch authentication into my app. I took a look at this article http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/190/how-to-use-fingerprint-authentication-in-cordova-phonegap-ionic-for-android-and-ios and it looked like exactly what I wanted. It used this https://github.com/mjwheatley/cordova-plugin-android-fingerprint-auth.git and https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-touch-id plugin.

Now this is when you find out I'm a newb with Angular and Ionic. How do I pass those functions into the controller, so that I can have something like this:

```
.controller('LoginController', function ($rootScope, $scope, $touchAuth) {
    $touchAuth.isAvailable(
    function() {
        alert('available!')
    }, // success handler: TouchID available
    function(msg) {
        alert('not available, message: ' + msg)
    } // error handler: no TouchID available

    $touchAuth.verifyFingerprint(
    'Scan your fingerprint please', // this will be shown in the native scanner popup
    function(msg) {
        alert('ok: ' + msg);
    }, // success handler: fingerprint accepted
    function(msg) {
        alert('Something is wrong: ' + JSON.stringify(msg));
    } // error handler with errorcode and localised reason
})
```

Basically what I want to know is how can I use these functions these plugins provide within my controllers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do this by making **service** or **factory**

> assuming this that you have installed the plugin successfully from :
>   https://github.com/mjwheatley/cordova-plugin-android-fingerprint-auth

you can use this in this way

> make a factory of $touchAuth

```
.factory('$touchAuth', function () {
  return {
     isAvailable : function(isAvailableSuccess, isAvailableError){
        FingerprintAuth.isAvailable(isAvailableSuccess, isAvailableError);
     }
   }
})
```

Now inject '**$touchAuth**' in your controller and then use it as the same way :

```
.controller('LoginController', function ($rootScope, $scope, $touchAuth) {
    $touchAuth.isAvailable(
    function() {
        alert('available!')
    }, 
    function(msg) {
        alert('not available, message: ' + msg)
    } 
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Muhammad (just jumping back on this task now). I seem to be getting the error ReferenceError: FingerprintAuth is not defined

Comment: have u installed the plugin successfully ?

Comment: yea ran cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-android-fingerprint-auth and I see the file in my file structure. I put the factory in my service.js file. My IDE is giving me a warning of Element is not exported for the FingerprintAuth object

Comment: Muhammad, your code worked fine. The issue is that I was testing with the browser and iOS. When I made a build with android things worked as expected, so I just need to put some device conditionals around my functions. Thanks for the help.